# NSArray with AnyObject on Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

How can I make it work:

```
var variable0 : Int = 10
var variable1 : [(name: String, title: String)] = []

variable1.append(name: "name 1", title: "title 1")
variable1.append(name: "name 2", title: "title 2")

var variable2 :NSArray = [variable0,variable1]
```

I would like a NSArray with this two variables.
But got a error on :

```
Type '[(name:String, title: String)]' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject
```

Comment: You can't. Tuples can't be represented in Objective-C and can't be stored using NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store it in an NSArray, but you can store it as  `Array<Any>` because Tuple does not conform to `AnyObject`:

```
var variable0 : Int = 10
var variable1 : [(name: String, title: String)] = []

variable1.append(name: "name 1", title: "title 1")
variable1.append(name: "name 2", title: "title 2")

var variable2 :Array<Any> = [variable0,variable1]
println(variable2[0]) // 10
println(variable2[1]) // [(name 1, title 1), (name 2, title 2)]
```

Comment: Cast it as the type of tuple it is

Comment: I can't find the object Tuple on swift : (variable2[1] as Tuple)[0].name does not work

Comment: println((variable2[1] as[(name: String, title: String)])[0].name )   
Is it the ok? or are there a better way?

Comment: I just find out I cant put this array inside a NSArray